# Retrieve Globalvalueset without Object_API_Name and Field_API_Name

Tags: apex, picklist, global-picklist

We used to retrieve Picklist values in Apex through and object and a field like this :

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = <Object_API_Name>.<Field_API_Name>.getDescribe();
Schema.sObjectField T = F.getSObjectField();
List<PicklistEntry> entries = T.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()
```

But now, I want to know if it's possible to retrieve Global Value Set in Apex directly through its name, and without using an Object name and a field name.

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this without using tooling or Metadata API.

Using tooling API you can retrieve it using the below pseudo codee,

```
String GLOBALVALUESETNAME = 'xyz'; //name of the global valueset you want to retrieve

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + System.userInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v50.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Metadata,Id+FROM+GlobalValueSet+WHERE+DeveloperName=\''+GLOBALVALUESETNAME+'\'');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http request = new Http();
HttpResponse res  = request.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It only return infos about the GLOBALVALUESET : `{"size":1,"totalSize":1,"done":true,"queryLocator":null,"entityTypeName":"GlobalValueSet","records":[{"attributes":{"type":"GlobalValueSet","url":"/services/data/v50.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/myId"},"Id":"myId"}]}`. I want to retrieve all the picklist values of the Global Value Set without using the Object name and the field name.

Comment: Updated the query! Check now

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get the following error : `[{"message":"\nSelect CustomValue,Id FROM GlobalValueSet\n ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:8\nNo such column 'CustomValue' on entity 'GlobalValueSet'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]`

Comment: Solved :). Just replaced `CustomValue` by `MetaData`  in the query

Comment: @kabrice This looks like a documentation bug! Hopefully, you acknowledge the approach suggestions I had for you